# Evaluating $\int \frac{\operatorname d \! x}{\sin^4{x}+\cos^4{x}+\sin^2{x}\cos^2{x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

How do you integrate

$$\frac{1}{\sin^4{x}+\cos^4{x}+\sin^2{x}\cos^2{x}}$$

or simply

$$\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{\sin{2x}}{2}\right)^2}.$$

Comment: I understand fixing the typesetting, but switching the style on whether to put parentheses around function arguments and where to put the exponents too?!?!

Comment: The two expressions are not equal. Note that $1+({\sin(2x)\over 2})^2=1+\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)\neq \sin^4(x)+\cos^4(x)+\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)$.

Comment: @PerManne It looks like the correct expression is supposed to be $\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{\sin{2x}}{2}\right)^2}$.

Comment: @DavidH it is - not +. Now editing the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the hint from David H in the comments, write
$$I=\int{{\rm d}x \over \sin^4(x)+\cos^4(x)+\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)}=\int{{\rm d}x\over 1-{1\over4 }\sin^2(2x)}$$
Several substitutions work here, but the simplest one is $u=\tan(2x)$. Then ${\rm d}u={2{\rm d}x\over\cos^2(2x)}$, so we divide by $\cos^2(2x)$ in the nominator and the denominator, and use that ${1\over \cos^2(2x)}=1+\tan^2(2x)$. This gives
$$I={1\over 2}\int{{\rm d}u\over 1+{3\over 4}u^2}$$
Let $v={\sqrt{3}\over 2}u$, then
$$I={1\over\sqrt{3}}\int{{\rm d}v\over 1+v^2}={1\over\sqrt{3}}\arctan(v)+C={1\over \sqrt{3}}\arctan\Bigl({\sqrt{3}\over 2}\tan(2x)\Bigr)+C$$

Comment: This is formally known as Weierstrass substitution(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)

Comment: I don't think that is correct. The substitution $u=\tan(x)$ would be the Weierstrass substitution, or the tangent half-angle substitution as Wikipedia calls it, since $x$ is half of $2x$. It always works for integrals of this type, but often leads to heavy work. The tangent substitution, which I have used, will work when all sines and cosines are raised to even powers, and can then be expected to give less work than the Weierstrass substitution, just as in this case.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int\frac{dx}{\sin^4x+\cos^4x+\sin^2x\cos^2x}=\int\frac{(1+\tan^2x)\sec^2x}{1+\tan^2x+\tan^4x}dx$$

Setting $\tan x=u,$

$$I=\int\frac{1+u^2}{1+u^2+u^4}du $$

Now as $\displaystyle 1+u^2+u^4=(1+u^2)^2-u^2=(1+u+u^2)(1-u+u^2),$

$\displaystyle\frac{2(1+u^2)}{1+u^2+u^4}=\frac{(1+u+u^2)+(1-u+u^2)}{(1+u+u^2)(1-u+u^2)}=\frac1{1+u+u^2}+\frac1{1-u+u^2}$

Now, $\displaystyle\frac1{1+u+u^2}=\frac4{(2u+1)^2+(\sqrt3)^2}$

Using [Trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution), set $\displaystyle2u+1=\sqrt3\tan\phi$

Similarly, for $\displaystyle\frac1{1-u+u^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that  $$\frac{1}{\sin ^{4}x+\cos ^{4}x+\sin ^{2}x\cos ^{2}x}\ne \frac{1}{1+\left( \frac{
\sin 2x}{2}\right) ^{2}}.$$

Since

\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{\sin ^{4}x+\cos ^{4}x+\sin ^{2}x\cos ^{2}x}=\frac{1}{1-\left( \frac{
\sin 2x}{2}\right) ^{2}}=\frac{4}{3+\cos ^{2}2x},
\end{equation*}

we will evaluate

$$I=\int\frac{4}{3+\cos ^{2}2x}\, dx.$$
We will use two substitutions: the trigonometric substitution $u=\cos 2x$ and the [Euler substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution)$\sqrt{1-u^{2}}=(u-1)t$ ([third substitution of Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution#The_third_substitution_of_Euler)) or $t=\frac{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}{u-1}$. We obtain the following [rational function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) of $t$ which is integrable by [partial fractions decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition). Each fraction is easily [integrable by completing the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square#Integration) in the denominator.

$$\frac{t^{2}+1}{t^{4}+t^{2}+1} = \frac{1}{2\left( t^{2}+t+1\right) }+ \frac{1}{2\left(
t^{2}-t+1\right) }.$$

We have that

\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=&-2\int \frac{1}{\left( 3+u^{2}\right) \sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\,du \\[2ex]
&=&\int \frac{t^{2}+1}{t^{4}+t^{2}+1}\,dt =\int \frac{1}{2\left( t^{2}+t+1\right) }dt+\int \frac{1}{2\left(
t^{2}-t+1\right) }dt \\[2ex]
&=&\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\arctan \frac{\sqrt{3}\left( 4t+2\right) }{6}+\frac{
\sqrt{3}}{3}\arctan \frac{\sqrt{3}\left( 4t-2\right) }{6}+C \\[2ex]
&=&\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\arctan \frac{\sqrt{3}\left( \frac{4\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}{u-1}
+2\right) }{6}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\arctan \frac{\sqrt{3}\left( \frac{4\sqrt{
1-u^{2}}}{u-1}-2\right) }{6}+C \\[2ex]
&=&\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\arctan \frac{\sqrt{3}\left( \frac{4\sqrt{1-\cos ^{2}2x}
}{\cos 2x-1}+2\right) }{6}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\arctan \frac{\sqrt{3}\left( 
\frac{4\sqrt{1-\cos ^{2}2x}}{\cos 2x-1}-2\right) }{6}+C \\[2ex]
&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan \frac{ -2+\tan x }{\sqrt{3}\tan x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan \frac{ 2+\tan x }{\sqrt{3}\tan x}+C.
\end{eqnarray*}